# databinding a list item within an object to a gridview column c#

Tags: c#, list, gridview, data-binding

I have a `List<>`, each object within this list contains another `List<>`. How would I go about accessing the list items to `databind` a `gridview` column. To bind the data, I am using:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contract Number">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblContractNum" runat="server" Width="100" CssClass="dataEntryLabel" Text='<%# Bind("ContractNum") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When I use the above code I get an error that states

```
System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'TimberSaleData' does not contain a property with the name 'ContractNum'.'
```

I have tried using `Text='<%# Bind("VolumesAndRates.ContractNum") %>'` but then I get the error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[VolumesAndRates, App_Code.q9rdyggz, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not contain a property with the name 'ContractNum'.'
```

This is what my TimberSaleData Object looks like:

```
public string LoggingUnitName { get; set; }
public string TractAllotNumber { get; set; }
public string ContractNumber { get; set; }
public string Seller { get; set; }
public string Purchaser { get; set; }
public string ApprovingOfficer { get; set; }
public decimal NumberOfBids { get; set; }
public DateTime BidDate { get; set; }
public DateTime ContractApproved { get; set; }
public decimal ContractAmount { get; set; }
public DateTime SaleClosureDate { get; set; }
public DateTime ExtensionApproved { get; set; }
public DateTime ExtensionCuttingEnds { get; set; }
public DateTime ExtensionExpirationDate { get; set; }
public decimal TotalValueForTract { get; set; }
public decimal TotalVolumeForTract { get; set; }
public decimal EstimatedBidValue { get; set; }
public decimal TotalAmountReceived { get; set; }
public decimal AdminExpenseDeductions { get; set; }
public decimal AdminExpenseDeductionsPercent { get; set; }
public DateTime CutPayDate { get; set; }
public decimal AcreageHarvested { get; set; }
public string SilviculturalTreatment { get; set; }
public string ReasonForHarvest { get; set; }
public string Remarks { get; set; }
public List<VolumesAndRates> VolumesAndRates { get; set; }
```

And this is what my VolumesAndRates object looks like:

```
public string ContractNum { get; set; }
public string TractNum { get; set; }
public string Species { get; set; }
public string Product { get; set; }
public decimal EstimatedVolume { get; set; }
public decimal ActualVolume { get; set; }
public decimal BaseRate { get; set; }
public decimal AppraisalRate { get; set; }
public decimal AdvertisedRate { get; set; }
public decimal BidRate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a `GridView`? If you can use `<asp:ListView>` then you can bind your data fairly simply into the table.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details

Then you could do like they do in the examples, with binding your data to the list view. You're going to have to relative path the datasource, but this snippet should get you started based on the info you provided.

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" DataSourceID="yourDataSource" ItemType="YourRoot.Models.TimberSaleData">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblContractNum" runat="server" Width="100" CssClass="dataEntryLabel">
              <%# Item.ContractNum %>
            </asp:Label>                
          </td>
          <td>
            <%# Item.Seller %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

The key here is the `ItemType` in the control. This allows you to bind your object properties, which makes it my preferred option.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be a `GridView`. I am going off what has already been made. I will give the `ListView` a shot and see what happens. Thanks